# Delphi 7 AlphaBlend not working for dynamic form

Tags: delphi, dynamic, transparency, alphablending

I have created dynamic Form as the next :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 Frm:TForm2;
begin

frm:=TForm2.Create(nil);
Frm.Left:=5;
Frm.Top:=5;
Frm.Parent:=Self;
Frm.OnCreate:=OncreateFrm;
Frm.Show;
end;
```

and when am trying to change the AlphaBlend  property, the transparency wouldn't change..

```
procedure TForm1.OncreateFrm(Sender: TObject);
begin
AlphaBlend:=True;
AlphaBlendValue:=200;
end;
```

Also overriding the constructor it gave the same result ..

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach

```pascal
Frm := TForm2.Create(nil);
Frm.Left := 5;
Frm.Top := 5;
Frm.Parent := Self;
Frm.OnCreate := OncreateFrm;
Frm.Show;
```

cannot possibly work because you set the `OnCreate` handler on line 5, which is *after* the form has been created on line 1; consequently, at the time the form is created (line 1), it sees that `OnCreate` is `nil` and so does nothing. Your instruction on line 5 has no effect.

This is like telling your fiend "Please buy some milk on your way home from work" *after* your friend has already come home from work.

## Solutions

### 1: Set the properties at design time

Of course, you can use the **Object Inspector** to set the `AlphaBlend` and `AlphaBlendValue` properties of `TForm2` at design time. But I suspect you want to do it dynamically, because you ask this question.

### 2: Use the `OnCreate` handler on `TForm2`

Just open `TForm2` in the form editor and double click it to give it its own `OnCreate` handler:

```pascal
// in Unit2.pas
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AlphaBlend := True;
  AlphaBlendValue := 128;
end;
```

### 3: Override `TForm2`'s constructor

```pascal
// in Unit2.pas
constructor TForm2.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  AlphaBlend := True;
  AlphaBlendValue := 128;
end;
```

### 4: Set the properties when you create the object

```pascal
// in Unit1.pas
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Frm: TForm2;
begin
  Frm := TForm2.Create(nil);
  Frm.Left := 5;
  Frm.Top := 5;
  Frm.AlphaBlend := True;
  Frm.AlphaBlendValue := 128;
  Frm.Show;
end;
```

Unlike the previous three approaches, this one affects only this instance of `TForm2` -- it doesn't affect the class itself.

All these approaches work.

## There is a "but"

Your line

```
Frm.Parent := Self
```

means that you make this form into a control instead of a top-level window.

And [layered windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features?redirectedfrom=MSDN#layered-windows) (the Win32 feature on which the VCL's `AlphaBlend` feature is based) are only supported as child windows in Windows 8 and later.

Therefore, if you are using Windows 7 or earlier, you cannot use `AlphaBlend` in this case.

Comment: I think that "But" is the reason for being not working , as I have tried all the above mentioned solutions.many thanks.

Comment: @Issam: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Am using Windows 7.

Comment: @Issam: Yes, then I'm afraid it is impossible to have a layered child window. Only top-level windows can be layered in Windows 7.